# ConversationHandler not going in state after normal message

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I have a conversation handler that is indeed triggered when I call the entry point /practiceflashcard

But then when I write a message, nothing happens and I would expect to go in the MessageHandler "guessing_word"

However, strange property: when I call /practiceflashcard again, I do indeed go to... the message handler

```py
application.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('practiceflashcard', practiceflashcard)],
        states={
            0: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, guessing_word)],
        },
        fallbacks=[]
    ))
```

And here are the functions :

```py
async def practiceflashcard(update, context):
    async def send(m):
        await context.bot.send_message(text=m, chat_id=update.effective_chat.id)

    sample = [('Bonjour', 'Hello'), ('Ça va?', 'You good?')]
    sentences = (x[0] for x in sample)

    await send('\n'.join(map("- {}".format, sentences)))

    context.user_data['sample'] = sample

    return 0

async def guessing_word(update, context):
    sample = context.user_data['sample']
    async def send(m):
        await context.bot.send_message(text=m, chat_id=update.effective_chat.id)
    answers = [x[1] for x in sample]
    await send('\n'.join(map("- {}".format, answers)))
    context.user_data.clear()
    return ConversationHandler.END
```

Answer (score 0):

My TEXT handler wasn't called because I had another TEXT handler in my handlers list that was added before. Therefore only this one was called.

Someone recommended me to use the "group" parameter of the "add_handler" method so that those handlers are separated in different groups.